# ListView not update when swipe to another page and back

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment, adapter

I'm writing a memo keeper app. It has a ViewPager that allows you to swipe between categories of memos. When I add a memo in a page, the memo is listed in the ListView of the fragment.

But if i swipe to another page and swipe back, then add another memo, that memo is not listed in the ListView. I tried `notifyDatasetChanged()` of the adapter and `invalidateViews()` of the ListView but nothing seem to work.

I don't know, where I made a mistake. I hope if you can find what I did wrong, it will very helpful for me.

Here is my Fragment code:

```
public class MemoListFragment extends Fragment
{
    private MemoAdapter memoAdapter = null;
    private ListView memoListView;
    private Memo memoToEdit = null;
    private List<Memo> userSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    private onDeleteActionSelectedListener 
    deleteActionSelectedListener;
    private String category;
    private List<Memo> memoList;

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

    private final int EDIT_MEMO_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

    public void updateMemoList(List<Memo> memoList)
    {
        memoAdapter.clear();
        memoAdapter.addAll(memoList);
    }

    public void setInitData(List<Memo> memoList)
    {
        this.memoList = memoList;
    }

    public void addMemo(Memo m)
    {
        memoAdapter.add(m);
        memoListView.invalidateViews();
    }


    public MemoListFragment()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);

        deleteActionSelectedListener = ((MainActivity) 
    context).getMainPresenter();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
    container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.memo_list_fragment, 
     container, false);

        memoListView = rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.memo_list_view);
        memoListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, 
     id) ->
        {
            {
                Memo selectedMemo = memoAdapter.getItem(position);

                Intent editMemo = new Intent(getActivity(), 
      MemoViewActivity.class);

                editMemo.putExtra("memo_to_edit", selectedMemo);

                memoToEdit = selectedMemo;

                startActivityForResult(editMemo, 
   EDIT_MEMO_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        memoAdapter = new MemoAdapter(getActivity(), 0, memoList);

        memoListView.setAdapter(memoAdapter);

    memoListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        memoListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(modeListener);

        return rootLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == EDIT_MEMO_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                String title = data.getStringExtra("title").toString();
                String detail = 
    data.getStringExtra("detail").toString();

                if (memoToEdit != null)
                {
                    memoToEdit.setDetail(detail);
                    memoToEdit.setTitle(title);
                    memoToEdit.setLastModified(LocalDate.now());
                    memoToEdit = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener modeListener = new 
  AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int 
   position, long id, boolean checked)
        {
            Memo m = memoAdapter.getItem(position);

            if (userSelected.contains(m))
            {
                userSelected.remove(m);
                memoAdapter.getSelectedPos().remove(new 
  Integer(position));
            }
            else
            {
                userSelected.add(m);
                memoAdapter.getSelectedPos().add(position);
            }


            memoListView.invalidateViews();

            mode.setTitle(userSelected.size() + " items selected.");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

            memoAdapter.setShowCheckboxes(true);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem 
  item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_delete:

                    for (Memo m : userSelected)
                        memoAdapter.remove(m);

   deleteActionSelectedListener.onDeleteActionSelected(userSelected);
                    mode.finish();

                    return true;


                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
        {
            userSelected.clear();

            memoAdapter.getSelectedPos().clear();
            memoAdapter.setShowCheckboxes(false);
        }
    };

    public interface onDeleteActionSelectedListener
    {
        void onDeleteActionSelected(List<Memo> userSelected);
    }


}
```

Here is the code to add a memo:

```
public void addMemo(Memo memo)
    {
        int currentPage = mainView.getCurrentPagePosition();

        if (currentPage == 0)//on page All category
            memo.setCategory("Not categorized");
        else

    memo.setCategory(memoManager.getCategoriesList().get(currentPage));

        MemoListFragment currentFrag = fragmentList.get(currentPage);
        currentFrag.addMemo(memo);

    }
```

Here is my PagerAdapter code:

```
public class MemooPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private FragmentSetupManager fragmentSetupManager;
    private List<String> categoriesList;

    public MemooPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, FragmentSetupManager fragmentSetupManager)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentSetupManager = fragmentSetupManager;
        this.categoriesList = fragmentSetupManager.getCategoriesList();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        MemoListFragment fragment = new MemoListFragment();

        String cate = categoriesList.get(position);

        fragment.setCategory(cate);
        fragment.setInitData(fragmentSetupManager.getFragmentData(cate));

        fragmentSetupManager.addToFragmentList(fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return categoriesList.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return categoriesList.get(position);
    }

    public interface FragmentSetupManager
    {
        List<Memo> getFragmentData(String category);

        void addToFragmentList(MemoListFragment fragment);

        List<String> getCategoriesList();
    }
}
```

ViewPager stetup:

```
public MainPresenter(MainView mainView)
    {
        this.mainView = mainView;
        memoManager = new MemoManager(((Activity) mainView).getApplicationContext());

        pagerAdapter = new MemooPagerAdapter(
                ((FragmentActivity) mainView).getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        mainView.setMainVPagerAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use this method `updateMemoList`?

Comment: Please show your viewpager creation and setup code (Fragment adapter etc,) . You have to remember that Viewpage pre-create fragments either side of the current fragment. e.g. on start page 0, page 1 is also created, if you add an item when on page 0 to page 1, when you swipe to page 1 it's onCreateView won't be called

Comment: @sanjeev It's old code and I haven't used it anywhere.

Comment: @Andrew Ok I will check that. Thank you

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around the sequence of events, so page 0 is "All categories", you swipe to page 1 (Say "Shopping List") and add a memo item to the "Shopping List", but are expecting the memo added in page 1 to also appear on page 0 when you swipe back to page 0 because it should display "All" memo items?

Comment: @Andrew actually, my problem is: for example you have 3 Tab: All category, Shopping list, To do list. You add a memo in All category tab, it is listed in the ListView, then swipe to To do list to view something. You return to All category, add a memo but it isn't listed in the ListView. But I have found the problem. In the `getItem()` in my PagerAdapter, when a fragment is created, it is add to the tail of the fragmentList and have a diffenrent index. But when add a memo, I still use the same index and it refer to the old Fragment. So i fixed the code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to communicate an event from one fragment to another. The easiest of ways is to use RXJava. This approach is the best way of doing that and easy to implement. In my opinion, this is the best approach for communicating two or maore fragments in Android.
Set up your project with the dependencies:

```js
  // RxJava2 Dependencies
  implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
  implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

So if you are in FragmentA and move to FragmentB, and made a change in FragmentB, FragmentA will get this change.

See how this was implemented easily [here](https://androidwave.com/fragment-communication-using-rxjava/). Do let me know if it is sufficient.